# Reuse same query across multiple group-bys?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-performance

I have a DB query that matches the desired rows. Let's say (for simplicity):

```sql
select * from stats where id in (1, 2);
```

Now I want to extract several frequency statistics (count of distinct values) for multiple columns, *across these matching rows*:

```sql
-- `stats.status` is one such column
select status, count(*) from stats where id in (1, 2) group by 1 order by 2 desc;

-- `stats.category` is another column
select category, count(*) from stats where id in (1, 2) group by 1 order by 2 desc;

-- etc.
```

**Is there a way to re-use the same underlying query in SqlAlchemy? Raw SQL works too.**

Or even better, return all the histograms at once, in a single command?

I'm mostly interested in performance, because I don't want Postgres to run the same row-matching many times, once for each column, over and over. The only change is which column is used for the histogram grouping. Otherwise it's the same set of rows.

Comment: It sounds to me like a temp table would serve your needs, though I might be mistaken.

Comment: Try to look at `grouping sets`: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) or [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-grouping-sets/) Probably you are interesting in something like `select status, category, count(*) from stats where id in (1, 2) group by grouping sets ((status), (category))`?

Comment: @Abelisto's comment is the answer. Sqlalchemy also supports `grouping_sets`, and you can use it like this: `select([Stats.status, Stats.category, func.count(1)]).filter(Stats.id.in_([1, 2])).group_by(func.grouping_sets(tuple_(Stats.status), tuple_(Stats.category))`

Comment: @HaleemurAli Can you post that as a full and complete answer? The SqlAlchemy version is non-trivial, let's not hide it in a comment.

Comment: Sure.  After I put the kids to bed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [Abelisto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593144/abelisto)'s comment & the other answer both have the correct sql required to generate the histogram for multiple fields in 1 single query.

The only edit I would suggest to their efforts is to add an `ORDER BY` clause, as it seems from OP's attempts that more frequent labels are desired at the top of the result. You might find that sorting the results in python rather than in the database is simpler. In that case, disregard the complexity brought on the order by clause.

Thus, the modified query would be:

```
SELECT category, status, count(*)
FROM stats
WHERE id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( 
  (category), (status) 
)
ORDER BY 
  GROUPING(category, status), 3 DESC
```

It is also possible to express the same query using sqlalchemy.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class Stats(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stats'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category = Column(Text)
    status = Column(Text)

stmt = select(
    [Stats.category, Stats.status, func.count(1)]
).where(
    Stats.id.in_([1, 2])
).group_by(
    func.grouping_sets(tuple_(Stats.category), 
                       tuple_(Stats.status))
).order_by(
    func.grouping(Stats.category, Stats.status),
    func.count(1).desc()
)
```

Investigating the output, we see that it generates the desired query (*extra newlines added in output for legibility*)

```
print(stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={'literal_binds': True}))
# outputs:
SELECT stats.category, stats.status, count(1) AS count_1 
FROM stats 
WHERE stats.id IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((stats.category), (stats.status)) 
ORDER BY grouping(stats.category, stats.status), count(1) DESC
```

Comment: Instead of the NULL checks I'd suggest ordering by `ORDER BY GROUPING(category, status), COUNT(1) DESC`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-GROUPING-TABLE

Comment: @IljaEverilä, thanks very much for that improvement. answer updated!

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want Postgres to run the same row-matching many times

That's one of the motivations behind the [GROUPING SETS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) functionality. Try this model:

```
SELECT category, status, count(*)
FROM stats where id in (1,2)
GROUP BY grouping sets ((category),(status));
```